# Counter Cache on a condition not on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, counter-cache

I've read on counter caches on associations.

Is there a way to easily implement (via a gem that will do the heavy lifting) of a counter cache for some condition? for example:

usually a counter cache would be

```
class User
  has_many :messages

class Message
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
```

however, lets say that I don't want to count how many messages, but to count the total number of characters in all of the messages from Joe

so lets say I have a method `count_chars_from(user)` that returns the number of chars from a user

I want to update a specific column when many thing occur in the system (when joe sends a message to several people - all of those users need to be updated, when joe edits a message to one person, etc)

This could be done with observers I guess, but I see myself creating ugly code very quickly.

Is there a way to have something like the above?

Comment: No there isn't, you have to implement it yourself, in a `before_save` for example

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no special methods/helpers for this. Rails doesn't support conditional counters.

However, you can simply define your own.

```
class Message
  belongs_to :user
  after_create :inc_counters
  after_destroy :dec_counters

  private
  def inc_counters
    if user && your_conditions
      user.increment(:conditional_counter)
    end
  end

  def dec_counters
    if user && your_conditions
      user.decrement(:conditional_counter)
    end
  end
end
```

I'd suggest take a look at [counter_cache implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb). It looks pretty complex, but simple implementation works in one of my project pretty well.
Also consider to use `update_column` to not trigger validations and callbacks on `User` model.
And test you code when you delete parent model if it has `dependent: :destroy` on association.